# RuntimeError: ALBroker::createBroker Cannot connect to tcp://100.82.32.131:9559

Tags: python, nao-robot, choregraphe

Im trying to run this code in NAO with python
from naoqi import ALProxy
tts = ALProxy("ALTextToSpeech", "100.82.32.131", 9559)
tts.say("Hello, world!")

and i get
RuntimeError:   ALBroker::createBroker
Cannot connect to tcp://100.82.32.131:9559

why i cant connect it?

Im trying to run this code in NAO with python
from naoqi import ALProxy
tts = ALProxy("ALTextToSpeech", "100.82.32.131", 9559)
tts.say("Hello, world!")

and i get
RuntimeError:   ALBroker::createBroker
Cannot connect to tcp://100.82.32.131:9559

why i cant connect it?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please improve your question by formatting it properly and explaining your network setup. Please also validate incoming edition requests.

Answer (score 0):

There can be plenty of reasons for this failure:

- The robot is not at this IP address
- The computer is not on the same network as the robot
- Some firewall prevents your program to connect
- NAOqi is not running